# Handling 'Routes' of Imported Modules on Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, jhipster

I'm having some difficulties in understanding/using the `routes` of an imported `module`. The problem occurs on `routes` that rely on *secondary outlets* or *named outlets*.

### The Problem

Suppose I have two modules `entity-a` and `entity-b`, and that `entity-a` imports `entity-b`, using its content via the *selector* `app-entity-b` on `entity-a.component.html`.

The content of `entity-b` will show perfectly on `entity-a`, however, ** `entity-b` links that refer to named outlets became broken**.

### Application Test

This test application on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gztxgn) illustrates the issue.

#### Routes are working within the module

- Click on **EntityB** to open `entity-b.component`.
- Click on **Entity B details** to open `entity-b-detail.component`.

#### Routes are broken once the module is imported

- Click on **EntityA** to open `entity-a.component`.
- `entity-a.componenet` is importing `entity-b.module` and showing `entity-b.component` that contains the link to `entity-b-detail.component`.
- Click on **Entity B details** and get an error:

  - `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'entity-a/a'`

### Things to take into consideration

- Modules `entity-a` and `entity-b` are being lazily loaded.
- `entity-a` is importing component `entity-b` and using its *selector* to show its content.
- If the `[routerLink]` makes reference to `entity-b` path before calling the `outlets` a *redirect* occurs to `entity-b` component, showing the `detail`. However, this isn't the expected behavior.

### Relevant code parts

#### `app.module`

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent
  }
];

const childRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'entity-a',
    loadChildren: './entities/entity-a/entity-a.module#EntityAModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'entity-b',
    loadChildren: './entities/entity-b/entity-b.module#EntityBModule'
  },
];

const ROUTES = [...childRoutes, ...appRoutes];
@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    RouterModule.forChild(childRoutes)
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, MainComponent, NavComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### `entity-a.module`

```js
const routeA: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: EntityAComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    EntityBModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routeA)
  ],
  declarations: [EntityAComponent],
  exports: [EntityAComponent]
})
export class EntityAModule { }
```

#### `entity-a.component.html`

```html
<h3>Entity A</h3>
<p>
Entity A Content
</p>

<div>
  <em>Importing 'Entity B'</em>
  <app-entity-b></app-entity-b>
</div>
```

#### `entity-b.module`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'b',
    component: EntityBComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'detail',
        component: EntityBDetailComponent,
        outlet: 'details',
      },
    ]
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    EntityBComponent,
    EntityBDetailComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    EntityBComponent,
    EntityBDetailComponent
  ]
})
export class EntityBModule { }
```

#### `entity-b.component.html`

```html
<h3>Entity B</h3>
<ul>
<li><a [routerLink]="[ { outlets: { details: 'detail' } }]">
  Entity B details
</a></li>
</ul>
<router-outlet name="details"></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing for named outlets work in combination with other routes. When you try to navigate to entity-b-detail from entity-a, it goes to the route `entity-a/a/(details:detail)`, and displays the result in named outlet. Since it doesn't find any match, it throws the error.

I've forked your code and made changes [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yb79qp).

The only relevant change was on `EntityModule`. `routeA` must hold a reference for path `a/detail`.

#### `entity-a.module`

```js
const routeA: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: EntityAComponent,
     children: [
      {
        path: 'detail',
        component: EntityBDetailComponent,
        outlet: 'details',
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Hello @Sachin, first of all, thank you for your time. So, how to solve my situation? Importing a `module` and injecting in another `module` and preserving it's `routes`.

Also, your code is throwing the following error when I try to access `details` from `entity-a`.
`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'entity-a/a'`

Comment: Sorry, the code might not have been saved. It's working now. The only change from your code ifs that i added the route config for named outlet in entity-a routes.

Comment: Got it. So, it is not possible to use the same *route* in this situation and the solution is to create another *route* that serves the same purpose, right? Frankly, this doesn't seem very elegant and throws some dirt over the separation of concerns... Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Yes, that would be a concern, but there can be other methods to avoid that. Maybe by using `ngComponentOutlet`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `ngComponentOutlet`. Do you have any example to share that accomplishes the same result I'm trying to achieve here? Also, I was thinking about editing you answer a little bit to illustrate what you changed in my code to be more useful for other users, are you ok with that? thank you!

Comment: Changes are always welcome. I'll try to make an example and share the code using `ngComponentOutlet`

Comment: I've added the usage of ngComponentOutlet https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzyvwy, see the example.

Comment: Awesome @Sachin! It is indeed a great approach! Thank you so much for your time =)

Comment: That code in stackblitz helped me as well, thank your guys. But I have an additional question, what if I need to pass parameters from entity A to entity B ?

In my case Entity B is a search page that has a filter field that we can use if we want to see the B entities that are related to entity A. It is a parent-children relationship.